# undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python6detail11init_moduleEPKcPFvvE' with Boost.Python, MinGW4.7 & Python2.7

Tags: c++, python-2.7, mingw, boost-python

I'm building the spotify/annoy library on Windows8 with Python 2.7 and MinGW 4.7,
first, I download boost 1.5.7 and successfully build Boost.Python with the following command:

```
b2 toolset=gcc --with-python
```

this generated serval libraries:

```
2015/03/18  10:27           707,484 libboost_python-mgw47-1_57.a
2015/03/18  10:25        10,851,410 libboost_python-mgw47-d-1_57.a
2015/03/18  10:23           707,484 libboost_python-mgw47-mt-1_57.a
2015/03/18  10:22        10,851,410 libboost_python-mgw47-mt-d-1_57.a
2015/03/18  10:30           707,484 libboost_python-mgw47-mt-s-1_57.a
2015/03/18  10:28        10,851,410 libboost_python-mgw47-mt-sd-1_57.a
2015/03/18  10:33           707,484 libboost_python-mgw47-s-1_57.a
2015/03/18  10:31        10,851,410 libboost_python-mgw47-sd-1_57.a
```

then, I built spotify/annoy with

```
python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32
```

it successfully generated the `annoymodule.o` file, but it got error with the link process, something like this:

```
E:\develop\Anaconda\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -DMS_WIN64 -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64
-2.7\Release\src\annoymodule.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\annoylib.def
 -LE:\develop\Anaconda\libs -LE:\develop\Anaconda\PCbuild\amd64 -lboost_python -
lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\annoy\annoylib.pyd
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\annoymodule.o:annoymodule.cc:(.text+0x366):
 undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python6detail11init_moduleEPKcPFvvE'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\annoymodule.o:annoymodule.cc:(.text+0x443):
 undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python7objects10class_baseC2EPKcyPKNS0_
9type_infoES4_'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\annoymodule.o:annoymodule.cc:(.text+0x46d):
 undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python9converter8registry6insertEPFPvP7
_objectEPFvS5_PNS1_30rvalue_from_python_stage1_dataEENS0_9type_infoEPFPK11_typeo
bjectvE'
```

I've tried all the library file generated by Boost.Python package, but it simply doesn't work.
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Run this whole __imp__... stuff through demangler, `c++filt`

Comment: thanks for the hints, with 'nm', I found my library didn't start with the '__imp__', hence the link error